# Nodejs Express Multiple Parameters Not Work Well

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to get two parameters from nodejs express but when I defined parameters as the below, I faced an issue and I could not solve it. My codes are these for routing:

```
app.use('/api/upcomingEvents/:trader/:id', require('./api/upcomingEvent'));
/* ther are inside of upocomingEvent/index.js */
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./upcomingEvent.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:trader/:id', controller.index);
```

When I send a request according to the defined routing, It give me the just first paramater. For example :

```
http://www.sitename.com/api/upcomingEvents/firstTrader/1
```

For this path express parameters like this  {trader:1,id:undefined}

If I change the path like this :

```
http://www.sitename.com/api/upcomingEvents/blablabla/firstTrader/1
```

It return the parameters as I want : {trader:'firstTrader',id:1}

How can I solve this problem?

api/UpcomingEvent/index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./upcomingEvent.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:trader', controller.index);
router.get('/:trader/:id', controller.index);
router.post('/:trader', controller.index);
router.post('/:trader/:id', controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

api/upcomingEvent/upcomingEvent.controller.js:

```
'use strict';
  // Gets a list of UpcomingEvents
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send(200,"ok!"); return;
};
```

Comment: share the code of `./api/upcomingEvent` .

Comment: Hi @MukeshSharma I shared them, too

Comment: You created a middleware for `/api/upcomingEvents/:trader/:id` this specific path and then pointed other routes with same variables. Why did you do that exactly ?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut yes,  as robertklep said, I declared same parameters. His suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `api/upcomingEvent.js`, you are declaring the same parameters again. In essence, you're creating routes to match this:

```
/api/upcomingEvents/:trader/:id/:trader
/api/upcomingEvents/:trader/:id/:trader/:id
```

Try this instead:

```
// app.js
app.use('/api/upcomingEvents', require('./api/upcomingEvent'));

// api/upcomingEvent.js
router.get ('/:trader',     controller.index);
router.get ('/:trader/:id', controller.index);
router.post('/:trader',     controller.index);
router.post('/:trader/:id', controller.index);
```

Since `:id` is optional, you can even shorten that to:

```
router.get ('/:trader/:id?', controller.index);
router.post('/:trader/:id?', controller.index);
```

Comment: `mergeParams` option solution seems only works on 4.5.0+ versions , is the other solution change parameter names only?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut yeah I thought it was better to move `/:trader` to `upcomingEvent.js` entirely, which would not require setting `mergeParams` anymore.

Comment: @robertklep yes you are right, thank you so much, it works wonderful